# BPMN: multiple timer start event leading to single event

Tags: bpmn

What's the proper way to model a multiple timer start event that would lead to single/similar event?

For example: a BPMN for an evaluation process in a company, there's annual evaluation for regular employees (1st timer start event) and there's an evaluation a month upon hiring for newly hired employees (2nd timer start event). Both timer would then lead to the same following event because the process for evaluation, regardless of type of employee, is the same (for this example).

This is what i had in mind, but i'm not sure if this is proper or right at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an issue with your process design is that one and only one process instance will be created each month and each year.

If my understanding is correct you want to create one instance each year for each employee and one each month for new comers.

What I suggest is to have two process definitions (one for annual and one for monthly evaluation) both using a call activity to instantiate a shared evaluation process.

The Annual evaluation process can use a parallel multi-instantiated call activity to create one evaluation process instance per employee.

The Monthly review process need to be manually started (or be part of an HR process) for each employee and have a loop design to trigger the evaluation process twelve times. I use a timer event to pause for a month between each iteration.

[image]

I designed the process with Bonita BPM 7.1.5 Community edition. So if you want you can [get the process definition](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yg8bz7dih5w5fj4/EvaluationProcessDiagram-1.0.bos?dl=0).